# Python: return statement still returns none from function

Tags: python, function, return

I've looked at all of the other "Returns none" questions on here and none of them seem to solve my problem.

```
rates = []
for date in unformatted_returns: # Please ignore undefined variables, it is redundant in this context
    if date[0] >= cutoff_date:
        date_i = unformatted_returns.index(date)
        r = date_initialize(date[0], date_i)
        print "r is returned as:", r
        rates.append(r)
        print date[0]
    else:
        continue

def date_initialize(date, date_i):
        print " initializing date configuration"
        # Does a bunch of junk
        rate_of_return_calc(date_new_i, date_i)

def rate_of_return_calc(date_new_i, date_i):
        r_new = unformatted_returns[int(date_i)] # Reverse naming, I know
        r_old = unformatted_returns[int(date_new_i)] # Reverse naming, I know
        if not r_new or not r_old:
            raise ValueError('r_new or r_old are not defined!!')
            # This should never be true and I don't want anything returned from here anyhow
        else:
            ror = (float(r_new[1])-float(r_old[1]))/float(r_old[1])
            print "ror is calculated as", ror
            return ror
```

The functions them selves work fine, the output is like so:

```
initializing date configuration
('2014-2-28', u'93.52')
ror is calculated as -0.142643284859
r is returned as: None
2015-2-2
>>>
```

`ror` is the correct value, but why does it not get returned when I have it written right there `return ror`?? Doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: There is no `return` in your `date_initialize` function. Thus it implicitly returns None.

Comment: Not to mention the syntax error this code would produce due to line 5.

Comment: Still @McLean : If you are posting codes it should be be syntax error free. As saying goes : When you are in Rome ,Do it like Romans.

Comment: @csharpcoder I must have accidentally deleted the bracket when I was indenting all of the content since it never copies over the way it should. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return it here too

```
def date_initialize(date, date_i):
        print " initializing date configuration"
        # Does a bunch of junk
        return rate_of_return_calc(date_new_i, date_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `date_initialize`, you need to return the function that is returning the value that you want.  Explicitly, change your call from

```
rate_of_return_calc(date_new_i, date_i)
```

to

```
return rate_of_return_calc(date_new_i, date_i)
```

Your first call, to `date_initialize`, does not return anything.  Therefore, when you call `rate_of_return_calc`, you receive the value and then throw it away.  You need to return it to pass the value along to your main function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value in date_initialize too:

```
def date_initialize(date, date_i):
    print " initializing date configuration"
    # Does a bunch of junk
    return rate_of_return_calc(date_new_i, date_i)
```